# How to "star" a URL in Google search programatically

Tags: google-api

I inevitably end up bookmarking a lot of sites because I think they might be useful in the future. Then two days later I have no idea what the bookmarks point to.

What I would like to do is instead star these bookmarks in google. That way when I do a similar search they will be shown at the top of the list, and I don't have a massive list of meaningless bookmarks.

Does anyone know if it is possible to star a url programatically? That way I can just write a script that will convert my bookmarks into google stared sites.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is currently a Google Bookmarks API, but there is an [open (and popular!) bug](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=120) open asking for one.